# geoLocation MongoDB query maxDistance

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript

Customer location:

```
customerCoordinates: [83,24]
```

stores:

```
 { id:1,
location: {coordinates:[85,44]...}
maxRadiusDelivery: 2000 //meters
},
{ id:2,
location: {coordinates:[82,34]...}
maxRadiusDelivery: 100 //meters
}
```

Query:

```
db.wh.find({
         'location':{
                    $near: {
                        $geometry: {
                            type: 'Point',
                            coordinates: costumerCoordinates,
                        },
                                $maxDistance: 1000,
                    },
                }
})
```

Is it possible to make a query that returns stores where distance between the customer and the store is not more than maxRadiusDelivery.

In this case the query returns sotores where distance between the costumer and the store is not more than hardcoded "1000"

Comment: What do you need at the end?

Comment: @Wolfetto I need All stores  where distance between the customer and the store is not more than the property maxRadiusDelivery inside the each store

e.g.  There are many stores that deliver food ... each store has own delivery Radius .. need all the stores that the customer is IN their delivery radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible using a simple query but you can work around that using an aggregation pipeline.

[$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) and other geospatial queries require a geospatial index, i.e they do not query the collection hence they can't access the document fields.

What you can do is use [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) which returns the distance from the input and then calculate whether or not `maxRadiusDelivery` is smaller than that.

```
db.wh.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: costumerCoordinates },
            distanceField: "calculated",
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $lte: ["$maxRadiusDelivery", "$calculated"]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

If you're on a Mongo version smaller than 4.2 then there's going to be a default limit of 100 documents for `$geonear` while you could obviously change it to the collection document count this seems to be unreasonable.

One more thing to note is that the `calculated` field could be returned in radians depending on how you store your coordinates. if that's the case you'll have to change the `$match` query to include the math to change it into either km or miles whatever it is you're using.